# Changing "background-image: linear-gradient" on li when selected - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to switch between two `CSS` classes using `jQuery`. The new class is being applied but it's as if the old style can't be removed, or is somehow overriding the new one. Either that or I am simply removing the wrong class, or removing it from the wrong element. Anyways, Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdb99/3/) you can use as a demo, and here is my code:

HTML

```
<nav id="as_nav">
    <ul class="acTypeNav">
        <li id="home_select"><a href="#Home" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
        <li id="roll_out_select"><a href="#Roll Out">Roll Out</a></li>
        <li id="construction_select"><a href="#Construction">Construction</a></li>                
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navHighlight {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#EEE3E3 5%, #C5DDF0 45%, #B3CEE5 51%);
    color: black;
}

.acTypeNav {    
    overflow: hidden;       
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:normal; 
}

.acTypeNav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #39f;  
    border-right: 1px solid #39f;   
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
    padding: 5px 55px 5px 55px;
    float:left; 
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE 5%, #E4F2FC 45%, #E8F3FD 51%);
}

.acTypeNav li:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE 5%, #E3F1FB 45%, #D2E8FB 51%);    
}

a:link    {     
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}

a:visited {
    color: #39F;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

a:active  {
    color: #000000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#roll_out_select").click(function (e) {

    var myNew = 'navHighlight';
    var myOld = 'acTypeNav li';
    $("#roll_out_select").removeClass(myOld);    
    $("#roll_out_select").addClass(myNew);
    console.log('removed' + ' ' + myOld + ', ' + 'added' + ' ' + myNew);

});
```

My last thoughts is that this must have something to do with the fact I'm using `background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE 5%, #E4F2FC 45%, #E8F3FD 51%);` in my class. This method of class swapping works on classes with normal `background-color:` tags with ease. This gradient seems to be giving me fits though. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied the `acTypeNav` class to `ul` element but is trying to remove it from the `li` element.

Instead you can give a default style and a highlighted style to the `li` element using

```
.acTypeNav li.navHighlight {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#EEE3E3 5%, #C5DDF0 45%, #B3CEE5 51%);
    color: black;
}
```

then

```
$("#roll_out_select").click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('navHighlight');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y4wVp/)

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks. I was really hoping I was simply selecting the wrong element and it wasn't something inherent with the CSS. Thank you! I will accept this answer ASAP